# Unable to update nested Model in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am creating poll app. My schema definitions are as below

```
var option = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: {type: String, required: true},
    votes: { type: Number, default: 0 }
});

var poll = new mongoose.Schema({
  question: { type: String, required: true, unique: true},
  options: { type: [option], required: true}
});
```

I have tried

```
app.put('/vote/:id', function(req, resp) { 
    Poll.findById(req.params.id , function(err, pol) { 
        pol.options.findById(req.body.id, function(err, option){// getting error in this line
            //do my stuff
        });
    });
});
```

But I am getting an error. How do I increase votes by one using mongoose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **[`$inc`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/)** update operator together with the [**`$`** positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#update-documents-in-an-array) as

```
app.put('/vote/:id', function(req, resp) { 
    Poll.findOneAndUpdate(
        { "_id": req.params.id, "options._id": req.body.id },
        { "$inc": { "options.$.votes": 1 } },
        { "new": true }
        function(err, pol) { 
            // pol contains the modified document
        }
    );
});
```

The [**`$`** positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#update-documents-in-an-array) facilitates updates to arrays that contain embedded documents like the `options` array in your case. It allows you to access the fields in the embedded documents with the [dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#document-dot-notation) on the [**`$`** operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#update-documents-in-an-array).

Comment: I am getting pol as null

Comment: It probably means the query did not find any matching document. Can you confirm that with the query `Poll.findOne({ "_id": req.params.id, "options._id": req.body.id }, function(err, pol) { console.log(pol); });`?

Comment: I am getting this as null. But same id exists in mongodb

Comment: Then like I said earlier, check your query parameters `req.params.id` and `req.body.id`, they aren't matching any documents in the collection otherwise the above should update well if it finds a match.

Comment: req.body.id was the getting as undefined. now working fine.

Comment: What about situations where you use update to either update an existing doc or create one if it still doesn't exist? Will the $ operator fail to find the non-existing document?